# Putting words from a file into a binary tree (C)

Tags: c, list, binary-tree

I'm currently learning C in Uni but for some reason it's just so difficult for me. I couldn't find a simple step by step guide and everything that's on the internet is just so complex and without much explanation. 
I'm supposed to write this program:

> 'Using the binary tree and list write a program that reads a text file and prints to the output file all the words in alphabetical order along with the line numbers in which the word occurs.'

And I just don't know how to start it. I can open files, run it from the command line, but I have no idea how to create a binary tree, get the words from a file and put them there, and then create a list inside the binary tree. All the examples I've found are so different that I don't know how to rewrite them so they would work for me.
Could anyone help? Even a few lines of code that would guide me in the right direction would help so much!

Comment: Do some research and write some code. You will get flamed for asking for help without demonstrating initiative.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a code-writing service.

Comment: @nicomp  I feel like I've read half the internet, that's the problem. I've been trying to write it for around 2h now and I currently have around 20 tabs open with different explanations and codes, but it all just jumps straight into it, I couldn't find anything that would explain binary tree or lists in a way that would teach me how to write them.

Comment: @Aglek Feel free for any queries. But don't expect someone to write the whole code for you.

Comment: @chrisaycock Sorry if it sounded like I wanted someone to write it for me, I'm rather interested in some explanation how to struct a binary tree with this specific conditions. Because everything I've read is just different enough that I don't know how to bite into it. And I'm still looking for some easy guide to constructing lists and a binary tree. Again, sorry, didn't mean to make it sound like that. Honestly I could use even a link to some good lesson how to do these stuff because I'm still searching...

Comment: Do it in stages — save intermediate steps in your version control system. (1) Write code to read a file line by line, and split each line into words, and print out each word with the line number where it appears. This gets the input handled. (2) Now keep a list of the words and for each word, a list of the line numbers. Modify the previous code to keep each distinct word in a list, and attach a new line number.  The efficiency of the 'find the word in the list' doesn't matter much.  You'll need to think what to do if 'and' or 'is' or 'the' occurs multiple times on a line. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Print the words in any order along with the list of line numbers. (3) Now you are ready to build a binary search tree (BST) instead of a list.  The input is much the same; you simply use your lecture notes to build a BST.  You need to compare words; is 'The' different from 'the'?  There are lots of questions here on Stack Overflow about BST; you can probably find all you need in some of them, but certainly it should be easy enough to adapt code to build the tree if you've done steps (1) and (2).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, its **[binary-search tree](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/binary_search_tree.htm)**,(special kind of binary tree) that is required for the given problem.

A `binary search tree`, is a binary tree, that is populated with **comparable** objects, like numbers. Meaning given two numbers `x` and `y`, the following three `boolean conditions` can be answered without any ambiguity.

```
x greater than y

x less than y

x equal to y
```

Now a `binary search tree` is built upon the above boolean conditions. The **analogy** here is that words are also **comparable**, which decides there order in a typical *oxford dictionary*. Like `apple < box` and therefore, `apple` comes before `box` in alphabetical order.

**How to get alphabetical order of words?**

Once you have populated your tree, a simple **[inorder traversal](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/)** will do the rest, that is, listing the words in alphabetical order. Just remember to also have variable for line numbers, which can be stored at the same time you are building your tree, which can later be retrieved while printing words in order.

Take the code as an exercise.

Comment: Thank You so much! The links look way easier to understand than what I've seen! That is pretty much what I was looking for. Not for anyone to write it for me, sorry if it seemed like that.